# bootstrap tabs next and previous buttons are not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have written code for tabs but its not working following is the html

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

  $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Shipping</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Quantities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i click on the button nothing happens no error on console

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, You just haven't included bootstrap.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Shipping</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Quantities</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am using laravel framework, its included bootstrap 4

Comment: i have spent almost a day in this i want to have a different tabs set for every user

Comment: means if visitor selects register as agent it will have different tabs set if it selects service provider it will show different tabs set and in that tabs i want registration fields

Comment: can u please give me something solutions for this problem